# MIPS - How does MIPS allocate memory for arrays in the stack?

Tags: assembly, malloc, mips, cpu-architecture

I'm quite new to the MIPS assembly language and am currently taking a class on computer architecture which has a large section on MIPS coding. I've studied several other high-level programming languages (C, C#, Python) in the past so have some bases in programming.

My question here specifically asks: How does MIPS allocate memory for arrays in the stack? I'm hoping that answering this question will hopefully give me a better total understanding of MIPS as I'm still a bit lot on conceptualizing the idea of the MIPS language and it's architecture. I don't quite understand how pointers work in this whole regard either...

Would be brilliant if someone could take the time to help out this confused student! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well.. you should be aware that MIPS, like C, essentially has three different ways of allocating memory.

Consider the following C code:

```
int arr[2]; //global variable, allocated in the data segment

int main() {
    int arr2[2]; //local variable, allocated on the stack
    int *arr3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); //local variable, allocated on the heap
}
```

MIPS assembly supports all these types of data.

To allocate an int array in the data segment you could use:

```
.data

arr: .word 0, 0 #enough space for two words, initialized to 0, arr label points to the first element
```

To allocate an int array on the stack you could use:

```
#save $ra
addi $sp $sp -4  #give 4 bytes to the stack to store the frame pointer
sw   $fp 0($sp)  #store the old frame pointer
move $fp $sp     #exchange the frame and stack pointers
addi $sp $sp -12 #allocate 12 more bytes of storage, 4 for $ra and 8 for our array
sw   $ra  -4($fp)

# at this point we have allocated space for our array at the address -8($fp)
```

To allocate space on the heap, a system call is required. In the spim simulator this is [system call 9](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html):

```
li $a0 8 #enough space for two integers
li $v0 9 #syscall 9 (sbrk)
syscall
# address of the allocated space is now in $v0
```

Answer (score 2):

MIPS unlike other archs doesn't have a push or pop register/immediate instruction. So you rely on managing the stack yourself. This is actually noted in most of the arch outside of mul/div where your registers don't have a specific use, just a suggested way to use it. Now if you used it however you wanted, you would break something if you tried to integrate with C for example.

In order to push something to the stack, you need to use a store instruction. These are `sb, sh, sw, swl, swr`. byte, half, word, word left, word right respectively.

```
addiu $sp, $sp, -4   # push stack 1 word
sw $t0, 0($sp)       # place item on newly pushed space
```

In order to pop something from the stack, you just need to deincrement it with addiu too. However, you may want to load the data from it using `lb, lh, lw, lwl, lwr`.

```
lw $t0, 0($sp)
addiu $sp, $sp, 4   # pop stack 1 word
```

Here is an example of using it with two word push.

```
addiu $sp, $sp, -8  # allocate two words
sw $t0, 0($sp)      # push two registers t0 t1
sw $t1, 4($sp)

lw $t1, 4($sp)      # pop two registers t0 t1
lw $t0, 0($sp)
addiu $sp, $sp, 8   # deallocate two words
```

Here is an example of using it for return addresses so calls to non-leaf functions don't mess you up.

```
# grab us a quick string
.data
example_str: .asciiz "hello world :^)"

# grab us a function
.text
    .globl example
    .type test, @function
test:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4  # push stack for 1 word
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      # save return address
    
    la $a0, example_str # call puts and give it a string
    jal puts
    nop
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)      # load return address
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4   # pop stack for 1 word
    
    jr $ra              # return from function to caller
    nop
```

Here is an example of pushing multiple elements in a row. Popping is the reverse of course.

```
.data
example_arr: .word 0, 0, 0, 0

.text
addiu $sp, $sp, -16
la $t0, example_arr
lw $t1, 0($t0)
sw $t1, 0($sp)
lw $t1, 0($t0)
sw $t1, 4($sp)
lw $t1, 0($t0)
sw $t1, 8($sp)
sw $t1, 12($sp)
```

Here is an example of using malloc/calloc thereof.

```
# grab us a function
.text
    .globl example
    .type test, @function
test:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4  # push stack for 1 word
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      # save return address
    
    li $a0, 4           # allocate 4*4 bytes (16)
    li $a1, 4
    jal calloc
    nop
    
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4  # push stack for 1 word
    sw $v0, 0($sp)      # save calloc'd buffer
    
    move $t0, $v0       # get the buffer into a temp
    li $t1, 1           # fill some temps with numbers
    li $t2, 2
    li $t3, 3
    li $t4, 4
    sw $t1, 0($t0)      # save some temps to buffer
    sw $t2, 4($t0)
    sw $t3, 8($t0)
    sw $t4, 12($t0)
    
    ... do stuff with the buffer ...
    
    lw $a0, 0($sp)      # pop buffer from stack
    jal free            # run it through free
    nop
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4   # don't forget to decrement
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)      # load return address
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4   # pop stack for 1 word
    
    jr $ra              # return from function to caller
    nop
```

Like I mentioned earlier, nothing has a hard defined specific use, so you can also use your own stack and forget about using $sp if you want. I shown examples where I was using $t* as $s*. This works in the case of forcing each function to have its own stack for instance or some other usecase you can think of. As one instance, Lua (https://lua.org) does this to some extent. However, not MIPS. Multiple stacks are lovely especially when dealing with multiple objectives.

Edit:
I realized that I omitted the stack frame pointer. Be aware of that if your code is linked with something written in C, that you properly handle the stack frame pointer.

Comment: It's unlike x86, but it's pretty typical for a RISC.  PowerPC and most other RISCs don't have push/pop.  (ARM isn't fully RISC, and its push/pop (store-multiple/load-multiple) are prime examples of ISA design that deviate from RISC philosophy to gain code density).

Comment: `sw 0($sp), 0($t0)`  A store instruction must have a register source, like `sw $t1, 0($t0)`!  [You can't do this even on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573554/what-x86-instructions-take-two-or-more-memory-operands).  I checked, and even MARS doesn't treat it as a pseudo-instruction using LW into `$at` for you, so you need to `lw` yourself.  Unless you're *really* confident in your knowledge / experience of an architecture, make sure your code at least compiles/assembles, even if you don't test-run it (because you're only showing a fragment that doesn't work on its own).

Comment: @PeterCordes I thought I fixed that lol. I did that for my own reference.

Answer (score 0):

In MIPS we manage the stacks manually, hence we use the store instructions “sb sh sw swl swr”