# What x86 instructions take two (or more) memory operands?

Tags: assembly, x86, instructions, machine-instruction

I thought that there was zero. But, [I see here,](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/)

> Instructions with two memory operands are extremely rare

I can't find anything that explains what instructions, though rare, exist. What are the exceptions?

Comment: The only ones I remember are the `movsb`, `movsw`, and `movsd` string instructions.  Their memory operands are implicit though.

Comment: Don't know why, but the link to nasmtutorial seems to be to an empty page, currently.

Comment: There’s also a new one in Tremont called MOVDIR64B.

Comment: @prl: Oh cool, that's a neat instruction.  Updated my answer.  Atomicity wider than 8 bytes is interesting (first time an x86 vendor has guaranteed anything other than 8 bytes and `lock cmpxchg16b`?)  In practice SKX probably has 64-byte load/store atomicity, but there's no clean way to take advantage for larger lock-free atomic objects because there's no guaranteed way to detect it.  So too bad `movdir64b` is only available in a cache-bypassing version that probably hurts performance for sharing data between threads.

Comment: *"explains the rarity"* simplicity of HW design,the memory was connected to CPU by address bus and data bus, and at single moment you could read/write only single value from/to it, by setting the address bus lines to contain the desired address of value, and data bus to value to be written (or wait for the data bus to be set by memory chip to the value read). So any two-memory operands are(were) implemented sequentially. Nowadays the CPU is lot more complex and memory access is layered under cache systems, but the one-mem-operand design seems powerful enough to not bother to change this way.

Comment: @Ped7g that's not what I was going for but I can see that interpretation will fix it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I can't find anything that explains the rarity.

An x86 instruction can have at most one ModR/M + SIB + disp0/8/32.  So there are zero instructions with two *explicit* memory operands.

The x86 memory-memory instructions all have at least one *implicit* memory operand whose location is baked in to the opcode, like `push` which accesses the stack, or the string instructions `movs` and `cmps`.

> What are the exceptions?

I'll use `[mem]` to indicate a ModR/M addressing mode which can be `[rdi]`, `[RIP+whatever]`, `[ebx+eax*4+1234]`, or whatever you like.

- `push [mem]`:  reads `[mem]`, writes implicit `[rsp]` (after updating `rsp`).
- `pop [mem]`
- `call [mem]`: reads a new RIP from `[mem]`, pushes a return address on the stack.
- [`movsb/w/d/q`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html): reads `DS:(E)SI`, writes `ES:(E)DI`  (or in 64-bit mode RSI and RDI).  Both are implicit; only the `DS` segment reg is overridable.  Usable with `rep`.
- [`cmpsb/w/d/q`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPS:CMPSB:CMPSW:CMPSD:CMPSQ.html): reads `DS:(E)SI` and `ES:(E)DI`  (or in 64-bit mode RSI and RDI).  Both are implicit; only the `DS` segment reg is overridable.  Usable with `repe` / `repne`.
- MPX [`bndstx mib, bnd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BNDSTX.html): "Store the bounds in bnd and the pointer value in the index register of mib to a bound table entry (BTE) with address translation using the base of mib."  The Operation section shows a load and a store, but I don't know enough about MPX to grok it.
- [`movdir64b r16/r32/r64, m512`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOVDIR64B). Has its own feature bit, available [in upcoming Tremont](https://fuse.wikichip.org/news/1158/intel-discloses-tremont-a-goldmont-plus-successor/) (successor to Goldmont Plus Atom).  Moves 64-bytes as direct-store (WC) with 64-byte write atomicity from source memory address to destination memory address.  Destination operand is (aligned atomic) `es:` `/r` from ModRM, source is (unaligned non-atomic) the `/m` from ModRM.

  Uses write-combining for the store, see the description.  It's the first time any x86 CPU vendor has guaranteed atomicity wider than 8 bytes outside of `lock cmpxchg16b`.  But unfortunately it's not actually great for multithreading because it forces NT-like cache eviction/bypass behaviour, so other cores will have to read it from DRAM instead of a shared outer cache.

AVX2 gather and AVX512 scatter instructions are debatable.  They obviously do multiple loads / stores, but all the pointers come from one SIMD vector (and a scalar base).

I'm not counting instructions like `pusha`, `fldenv`, [`xsaveopt`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/XSAVEOPT.html), `iret`, or `enter` with nesting level > 1 that do multiple stores or loads to a contiguous block.

I'm also not counting the `ins` / `outs` string instructions, because they copy memory to/from I/O space.  I/O space isn't memory.

I didn't look at VMX or SGX instructions on http://felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html, just the main list.  I don't think I missed any, but I certainly could have.

Comment: Does any instruction has 4 explicit operands? Because this (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html) website reserves 4 columns in operands table for all instructions.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: Yes, `vpblendvb` / `vblendvps/pd`, but still only one can be memory.  [What kind of address instruction does the x86 cpu have?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53325275).  Note that https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ is just scraped from Intel's own PDF manual.