# x86_64 cmp instruction invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm new to NASM and x86_64 assembly. I'm confused with [wiki document](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Comparison_Instructions) for **cmp** instruction. As per the document operands could be either one of below.

> cmp minuend, subtrahend
>
> **minuend**
>
> AL/AX/EAX (only if subtrahend is immediate)
> Register
> Memory
>
> **subtrahend**
>
> Register
> Immediate
> Memory

when I try to compile below code snippet.

```
var_1 dd 100
var_2 dd 200
cmp dword[var_1], dword[var_2]
```

it throws an error: **invalid combination of opcode and operands**

but after I change the cmp instruction to below it compiles fine.

```
var_1 dd 100
var_2 dd 200
mov eax, [var_1]
cmp eax, dword[var_2]
```

But as per the wiki document, both the operands could be a memory if so then the first code snippet should be compiled. It would be really helpful if anyone explains me this syntax clearly.

Comment: What the document means to say is that **either** operand can be memory. It doesn’t mean **both**, but that isn’t clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But as per the wiki document, both the operands could be a memory if so then the first code snippet should be compiled.

No. This is wrong. The x86 architecture in general only allows one memory operand per instruction. So

```
mov eax, [var_1]
cmp eax, dword[var_2]
```

is valid, because each instruction only has one memory operand.
This principle reaches its bounds in some of the newest x86_64 SIMD instructions.
This [SO answer describes some (possible) exceptions to the rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52573554/1305969).