# 'wrong parameters' while using pointer in assembly, what's wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I learned in the class that we can use pointers in assembly with these brackets [].
but in my program that dosent work and give me 'wrong parameters error'.
will be very happy if you help me :)

```
cmp [cx], num
JNE LOOP1
inc count
jmp LOOP1
```

how you can see, i try count number of "num" in an array, and there is problem with the first line

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: x86 assembly doesn't support two [explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52573554) memory operands in one instruction.

So your first instruction `cmp [cx], num` is invalid. Load one of the arguments into a register first, and then execute the comparison (for example, like this):

```
mov ax, num     ; preferably outside the loop
cmp [cx], ax
JNE LOOP1
inc count
jmp LOOP1
```

This should fix that problem.

`[cx]` isn't a valid 16-bit addressing mode either, so pick BX, SI or DI instead for iterating a pointer over the array.

Answer (score 0):

I get it, the problem was that I made cx a pointer, but the only bx, di and si can be pointers.
so now my code looks like this :

```
mov bx, cx
cmp [bx], ax
JNE LOOP1
inc count
jmp LOOP1
```